# tokenized_docs= [(i, tokenize(doc)) for i, doc in tqdm (docs[:])] ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, tokenize, tqdm

i'm try to run lda2vec algorithm from https://github.com/sebkim/lda2vec-pytorch with my own data.when i'm tried the model preprocess.py `from collections import Counter
from tqdm import tqdm

def preprocess(docs):
"""Tokenize, encode documents.

```
Arguments:
    docs: A list of tuples (index, string), each string is a document.

Returns:
    encoded_docs: A list of tuples (index, list), each list is a document
        with words encoded by integer values.
    decoder: A dict, integer -> word.
    word_counts: A list of integers, counts of words that are in decoder.
        word_counts[i] is the number of occurrences of word decoder[i]
        in all documents in docs.
"""

def tokenize(doc):
    return doc.split()

tokenized_docs= [(i, tokenize(doc)) for i, doc in tqdm (docs[:])]

counts = _count_unique_tokens(tokenized_docs)
encoder, decoder, word_counts = _create_token_encoder(counts)
encoded_docs = _encode(tokenized_docs, encoder)
return encoded_docs, decoder, word_counts
```

def _count_unique_tokens(tokenized_docs):
tokens = []
for i, doc in tokenized_docs:
tokens += doc
return Counter(tokens)

def _encode(tokenized_docs, encoder):
return [(i, [encoder[t] for t in doc]) for i, doc in tokenized_docs]

def _create_token_encoder(counts):

```
total_tokens_count = sum(
    count for token, count in counts.most_common()
)
print('total number of tokens:', total_tokens_count)

encoder = {}
decoder = {}
word_counts = []
i = 0

for token, count in counts.most_common():
    # counts.most_common() is in decreasing count order
    encoder[token] = i
    decoder[i] = token
    word_counts.append(count)
    i += 1

return encoder, decoder, word_counts
```

def get_windows(doc, hws=5):
"""
For each word in a document get a window around it.

```
Arguments:
    doc: a list of words.
    hws: an integer, half window size.

Returns:
    a list of tuples, each tuple looks like this
        (word w, window around w),
        window around w equals to
        [hws words that come before w] + [hws words that come after w],
        size of the window around w is 2*hws.
        Number of the tuples = len(doc).
"""
length = len(doc)
assert length > 2*hws, 'doc is too short!'

inside = [(w, doc[(i - hws):i] + doc[(i + 1):(i + hws + 1)])
          for i, w in enumerate(doc[hws:-hws], hws)]

# for words that are near the beginning or
# the end of a doc tuples are slightly different
beginning = [(w, doc[:i] + doc[(i + 1):(2*hws + 1)])
             for i, w in enumerate(doc[:hws], 0)]

end = [(w, doc[-(2*hws + 1):i] + doc[(i + 1):])
       for i, w in enumerate(doc[-hws:], length - hws)]

return beginning + inside + end`
```

but i'm getting this error
`Traceback (most recent call last):ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`
how i fix this error.

Comment: Have a look at what line is pointed in the error then check if you didn't do `a, b = some_stuff` where some_stuff has more than 2 values. You can print or debug before unpacking to check.

Comment: i don't understand, please  explain to me again

Comment: Unpacking is when you affect a composed variable, a tuple for example, to a list of variables (coma separated). You have to have exactely the same amount of elements in your tuple than the variables (or use a star before the last variable so it absorbs all the remaining elements)